# Appium - Element found but returning error as not clickable

Tags: ios, appium

I have an app where there is sign-out button if the form of UIImage with an gear icon.The element name is called settings_icon. What I am trying to do is a simple tap on that button to invoke a view through appium.Appiun is able to find the element but for some reason, it is returning not able to tap that element. Below is the log

> info: <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e/elements 200
>   1566.971 ms - 105 {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"6"},{"ELEMENT":"7"}],"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e"}
>
> info: --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e/elements
>   {"using":"name","sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e","value":"settings_icon"}
>
> debug: Pushing command to appium work queue:
>   "au.getElementsByName('settings_icon')"
>
> debug: Sending command to instruments:
>   au.getElementsByName('settings_icon') debug: Sending command to
>   instruments: au.getElementsByName('settings_icon')
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:39 +0000 Debug: Got new command 16 from
>   instruments: au.getElementsByName('settings_icon')
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:39 +0000 Debug: evaluating
>   au.getElementsByName('settings_icon')
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:40 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:40 +0000 Debug: **Lookup returned [object
>   UIAImage] with the name "settings_icon" (id: 8).**
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:40 +0000 Debug: responding with:
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:40 +0000 Debug: Running system command
>
> ## 17: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"8"}]}...
>
> debug: Socket data received (40 bytes)
>
> debug: Socket data being routed. debug: Got result from instruments:
>   {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"8"}]} debug: Responding to client
>   with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"8"}],"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e"}
>
> info: <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e/elements 200
>   1450.216 ms - 89 {"status":0,"value":[{"ELEMENT":"8"}],"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e"}
>
> info: --> POST
>   /wd/hub/session/6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e/element/8/click
>   {"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e","id":"8"}
>
> debug: Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.tapById('8')"
>
> debug: Sending command to instruments: au.tapById('8') debug: **Sending
>   command to instruments: au.tapById('8')**
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:41 +0000 Debug: Got new command 17 from
>   instruments: au.tapById('8')
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:41 +0000 Debug: evaluating
>   au.tapById('8')
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:41 +0000 Debug: UIAImage.tap()
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:41 +0000 Debug: **UIAImage could not be
>   tapped**
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
>
> debug: Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.1","revision":"2a4b624a708e580709006b697dc4c9c4e3007863"}},"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e"}
>
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.008 ms - 155
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.1","revision":"2a4b624a708e580709006b697dc4c9c4e3007863"}},"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e"}
>
> debug: [INST] 2014-09-04 13:15:41 +0000 Error: VerboseError: elementId
>   8 could not be tapped
>
> debug: Socket data received (57 bytes)
>
> debug: Socket data being routed. debug: Got result from instruments:
>   {"status":13,"value":"elementId 8 could not be tapped"}
>
> info: <-- POST
>   /wd/hub/session/6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e/element/8/click
>   500 3509.769 ms - 200
>
> debug: Responding to client with error:
>   {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command.","origValue":"elementId 8 could not be
>   tapped"},"sessionId":"6ac7b1be-ed67-465e-8a70-0792b65f455e"}

The element is tappable when I do it manually. I tried with path as well as name of the element but no luck. Even in Appium inspector when I locate the element and performa TAP it is not working.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Adding the Element Attributes as returned by Appium

```
<UIAImage name="settings_icon" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="false" hint="" path="/0/0/3" x="0" y="737" width="140" height="22">
        </UIAImage>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you actually have a UIButton or another UI element on top of the UIImage that is tappable? If that is so, you should be able to see this other element with the Appium Inspector.

If that doesn't work, you can try to use precise tap and tap on the element using exact coordinates. See this link for example for info on how to use the tap command with coordinates:
http://appium.wikia.com/wiki/Mobile_Commands

Comment: I checked with the structure and I didn't find any UIButton. However, I overcome the issue by using precise tap of an element and automated my script using precise tap (X and Y Coordinates)

Comment: I'll edit the answer to include the precise tap info!